# kerberos ticket watcher

Tags: kerberos

I just switched from openSuSe to Ubuntu 12.04. At work we use kerberos to auth to different systems. In openSuSe I had a nice little tray app "kerberos ticket watcher" that could renew and initialise new tickets as they expired.

I have installed "kerberos authentication", but I can't find out how to run it from the tray (background). The version is 3.2.1 (last stable release).

So the question is... can I have kerberos authentication running as a tray app or is there some other app that can solve this?

I have seen this solution, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1575699, but I would prefer to have a dedicated app for it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found this: http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/monitor-kerberos-authentication-tickets-in-ubuntu-linux-with-network-authentication/

Unfortunately it is not integrate in Unity!